# Can we change ERC721 mapping Access Modifier?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, remix, ethereumjs

I am using openzeppelin ERC721 smart contract. That smart contract have a mapping's called :

`mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;`
`mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;`

Can we change their type from **private** to **public** without violating the ERC721 standard? Or will it violate the standard.

My use-case is that I want to update their value inside a function call but since they are private I cannot inherit them to update or modify.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions that you can modify or retrieve the state of the contract itself, which makes it a standard. Using these provided functionalities, these private state variables can be manipulated. Changing these variables from `private` to `public`, and implementing different functions that can manipulate these state variables would make it a different type of contract that may not be fitting in **ERC721** standards. That doesn't mean you cannot invent or develop a new way of a contract standart, however it won't be **ERC721** anymore.